# What is the proper way to stop Jenkins (when executing the war as standalone)?

Tags: linux, jenkins, init.d

I am running Jenkins as a jar (via `java -jar jenkins.war`). I would like to create a simple `init.d` script, as I can't seem to find one for this kind of scenario. What would be the proper way to shut it down? I mean... `kill -9` doesn't look like the best way to me...

Any advice on how to best implement this, or could somebody perhaps point me to an existing such script?

Answer (score 0):

The official Jenkins documentation contains such a script if you run it installed: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsLinuxStartupScript

If you run it as a jar, see the "Linux service - systemd" in the diocumentation: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon

Comment: The first link you've pointed shows an example for a case where you have Jenkins running inside Tomcat. I'm using the embedded Jetty, part of the `war` file.